How to get out of the Help options? Help on topic ‘xyz’ was found in the following packages:
I have been working with R for a while, yet I am unable to find out how to quit or select the relevant package in Help options prompt when a function is in multiple packages
Here is an example:
> ?grep
Help on topic ‘grep’ was found in the following packages:

  Package               Library
  BiocGenerics          /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library
  base                  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library

Tried several options including Ctrl^C yet R is not quitting the prompt.
I found the following question, and understand the way to seek help from a specific package but it does not answer my question.
How to specify the package when looking up a help reference page for a function?

Usually if you're in text mode with help() it opens in something that looks like vim, and there's a little : prompt, and you can scroll by pressing space and exit by entering q. But in my experience where there's a conflict, even in text mode a little window pops up and asks you to choose, before taking you into the help page. Are you sure nothing pops up?

Please add info:  what OS?  are you using a console inside a GUI , or , if not, what kind of terminal -- bash,  ksh,  whatever Windows now calls their command-line?

I might add: unless there's some huge reason not to do so,  install an IDE gui  and work there.

Thanks both. @SamR - You are right about the : prompt but I am stuck before entering the help description page, as it expects me to choose the right package (no prompt and q does nothing). @Carl Witthoft - I am Terminal in macos 14.2.1 (intel) - No GUI, just the console. Mac's default shell is bash.

Using VScode to switch between R and Python usually. Copy/paste R code into Terminal.

@SamP. If you're using VS Code why not use just the R extension? Then your help pages will open in http mode. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r

Thanks @SamR. That is surely an alternative. As you know, there is no lack of alternatives, as I could just google and get the R help docs these days. I am missing something simple here - as to how to select the package or get out of package selection. The minor issue in all these is that I accidentally use ?xyz and end up killing the whole R process because it is unclear how to get out of it.

@SamP. fair enough but it's hard to suggest a fix without being able to reproduce the problem. If you want a workaround why not just add a line to your .Rprofile overwriting the ? function to open in html mode. Something like \?` <- function(x) help(deparse(substitute(x)), help_type = "html")? Or if you don't have access to html mode, or don't want to reproduce all the logic of ?, something like`?`  <- (x) message("use the help() function")`
